# Distance traveled by a car with a reaction time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration

So I have been doing this homework problem and my teacher gave me the answer, **51 seconds** according to him, but I can't seem to get the correct answer.

This is the problem:

*A police car is traveling at a velocity of 18.0 m/s due north, when a car zooms by at a constant velocity of 42.0 m/s due north. After a reaction time 0.800 s the policeman begins to pursue the speeder with an acceleration of 5.00 m/s^2. Including the reaction time, how long does it take for the police car to catch up with the speeder?*

So this is my work:

I started by obtaining the distance traveled by both the cop and the car during the reaction time, which was 0.8secs

I will call cop with subscript p (for police) and the other car with subscript c for (car)

**Distances during the reaction time (0.8secs)**

$$Distance_p = 18m * 0.8 = 14.4$$
$$Distance_c = 42m * 0.8 = 33.6$$

So by the end of the reaction time, the cop has  a disadvantage of 19.2m (33.6m - 14.4m), meaning the car has a lead of 19.2 meters. Now I use that information using the kinematic equations:

Same subscripts, c for car, and p for police car

$$X_c = 42t + 19.2$$ 
$$X_p = 18t + 2.5t^2$$

Now I am looking for the time when the police catches up to the car, so I set both of those equations equal to each other to find the distance at which both times are the same:

$$18t + 2.5t^2 = 42t + 19.2$$
$$18t + 2.5t^2 - 42 - 19.2 = 0$$
$$2.5t^2 - 24t -19.2= 0$$

And then use the quadratic formula to solve for t:

$$\frac{24 ± \sqrt{24^2 - (4)(2.5)(-19.2)}}{(2.5)(2)}$$

After simplifying that I end up with a negative value for t, but that would be impossible to have negative time, and **t = 10.3secs + 0.8 = 11.1secs**

How am I going wrong, my answer is way off from what my teacher told me, which was 51 secs?

Thank you

Comment: You have used 42 when the question says 48, and forgotten to add the initial reaction time at least.  It is perhaps easier to work in a frame where the police car is initially at rest (although this may not be something you know how to do yet).

Comment: My mistake, the problem does say 42, but I mistyped! fixed, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the poistion of car, $x_c$ and police car, $x_p$ to be $0$ at $t=0$.

Due to the reaction time $t_r$ the car has a slight headstart:

$$x_c=v_ct+v_ct_r$$
 For the police car:

$$x_p=v_pt_r+v_pt+\frac12 a_pt^2$$

The police car catches up with the speeder when:

$$x_c=x_p$$

Solve for $t$.

Comment: I see that you are considering the distance traveled by the car in the reaction time. However, didn't the police car also travel a distance during that reaction time? I don't think you are accounting for that?

Comment: Yeah it ends up being the same quadratic I had up there, thanks! Just wanted to confirm before I went up to my teacher to tell him he might have made a mistake